# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{k \geq 0} \cos(k)z^k$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{k \geq 0} \cos(k)z^k$.

I was trying to use the root test or ratio test, but the only thing I know is
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}[\cos(k)]^{1/k}\leq 1$$
And I can only say the radius of convergence $R \geq 1$. Can anyone give a more rigorous result? Thanks!

Comment: There are infinitely many integers such that $1/2 \le \cos(k) \le 1$, so it's easy to check that $\limsup_{k \to \infty} (\cos k)^{1/k} = 1$ and the radius is $1$.

Comment: Also, careless formal manipulations bring the original series (assuming $z\in\mathbb{R}$) into $$\text{Re}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(z e^i\right)^k = \text{Re}\frac{1}{1-z e^i}=\frac{1-z\cos(1)}{1+z^2-2z\cos(1)}$$ with simple poles on the unit circle.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think you mean $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} [(z e^i)^k + (z e^{-i})^k]$ - the real part of $\frac{1}{1 - z e^i}$ wouldn't be an analytic function.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: you are correct, my previous manipulation started by assuming $z\in\mathbb{R}$ (so $z^k \cos(k)=\text{Re}(z e^i)^k$), but finished by interpreting the RHS as a function of the complex variable $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos (k)z^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ik}+e^{-ik}}{2}z^k$$so the convergence radius is where $|ze^i|<1$ and $|ze^{-i}|<1$ which leads to $|z|<1$ and $R=1$